# how to add row on android

Tags: java, android, view, row

i follow tutorial from [here](http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-add-row-dynamically.html?showComment=1384142166303#c5120729117421735009) to add row, but i face the problem, i got problem when i'm trying to add view... this is my code :

```
add_sumber_pp=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add_sumber_pp);

add_sumber_pp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        TableLayout tablelayout_penghasilan_pp=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout_penghasilan_pp);
        TableRow tabel_penghasilan_pp=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tabel_penghasilan_pp);
        counter++;
        TextView adapter_no_dana=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adapter_no_dana);
        TextView adapter_jenis_dana=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adapter_jenis_dana);
        TextView adapter_jelaskan_dana=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adapter_jelaskan_dana);
                ImageView add_pp=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add_pp);
                ImageView remove_pp=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.remove_pp);
                adapter_no_dana.setText("anak "+counter);
                if(v != null) 
                { 
                     ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                        if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                            parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
                        }

                }
                tabel_penghasilan_pp.addView(adapter_no_dana);
                tabel_penghasilan_pp.addView(adapter_jenis_dana);
                tabel_penghasilan_pp.addView(adapter_jelaskan_dana);
                tabel_penghasilan_pp.addView(add_pp);
                tabel_penghasilan_pp.addView(remove_pp);

            }
        });
```

this is my logcat :

```
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3389)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3260)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3205)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3181)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at id.co.ajsmsig.formspaj.Pemegang_polis$6.onClick(Pemegang_polis.java:308)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17337)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
11-11 11:39:29.944: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my layout :
[image]

i don't know where is my fault.. i hope there is someone can help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me,
these views

```
 TextView adapter_no_dana=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adapter_no_dana);
        TextView adapter_jenis_dana=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adapter_jenis_dana);
        TextView adapter_jelaskan_dana=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.adapter_jelaskan_dana);
```

are childs of another layout/parent, that is the problem.

if you want to add them dynamically, you need to make changes as

```
TextView adapter_no_dana=new TestView(context);
        TextView adapter_jenis_dana=new TestView(context);
        TextView adapter_jelaskan_dana=new TestView(context);
```

Comment: Here context refers to your activity context (Your_Activity_name.this)

Answer (score 0):

Add following line before updating your view

```
tablelayout_penghasilan_pp.removeAllViews();
```

Yes if you want to add dynamically, you should update this in your code

```
TextView adapter_no_dana=new TestView(context);
TextView adapter_jenis_dana=new TestView(context);
TextView adapter_jelaskan_dana=new TestView(context);
```

Hope it will help you.